# Change a character in a column depending on a instruction from another column

Tags: linux, text-processing, awk, sed, bioinformatics

I am trying to set up a script which will convert a codon sequence to another codon sequence depending on variants I find in my NGS data.

Currently, My script creates a tab-delimited output file, With 6 columns. Each column represents the following:

- 1st: Genome position
- 2nd: Nucleotide base
- 3rd: Codon
- 4th: Genome position order in the codon
- 5th: SNP frequency
- 6th: SNP Base

The output data looks like this:

```
2289     G       GTG    3        0.0346505      A

2478     G       ATG    2        0.0054087      C
```

Is it possible to set up a 7th column in the output file, which changes the nucleotide sequence of the codon depending on the number in column 4, to the SNP nucleotide (column 6)?

For example,

- For genome position 2289:

The codon GTG would become GTA. The SNP nucleotide A replaces the 3rd nucleotide sequence in the codon, the codon sequence order is specified in column 4.

- For genome Position 2478

The codon ATG would become ACG. The SNP nucleotide C replaces the 2nd nucleotide sequence in the codon.

Is it possible to use `awk` or `sed` to do this?

Comment: @JeffSchaller I reverted the edit because losing the output format makes it harder to determine the answer...

Comment: Fair enough, @StephenKitt — it looked more readable to me, but I wasn’t trying to answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was so tempting to just answer "yes" to the question "is it possible to....".

Would something like this do?

```
awk '{l=substr($3,1,$4-1); r=substr($3,$4+1); print $0"\t"l $6 r}' genome > mutated
```

Answer (score 1):

Perl solution:

```
perl -lane 'substr $n = $F[2], $F[3] - 1, 1, $F[5]; print join "\t", $_, $n' -- file
```

- `-n` reads the input line by line
- `-l` removes newlines from input and adds them to [print](http://p3rl.org/print)s
- `-a` splits each line on whitespace into the @F array
- see [substr](http://p3rl.org/substr) for details

Answer (score 1):

With some `perl` splitting and joining:

```
perl -alne '
  @c = split //, $F[2]; 
  splice @c, $F[3]-1, 1, $F[5]; 
  print join "\t", @F, join "", @c;
' data
```

Explanation:

```
- split 3rd column into character array @c
- replace the value indexed by the 4th column with that of the 6th
- stitch it all back together, delimited by tabs
```

Testing - given

```
$ cat data
2289    G       GTG     3       0.0346505       A
2478    G       ATG     2       0.0054087       C
```

then

```
$ perl -alne '
    @c = split //,$F[2]; splice @c,$F[3]-1,1,$F[5]; print join "\t",@F,join "",@c
  ' data
2289    G       GTG     3       0.0346505       A       GTA
2478    G       ATG     2       0.0054087       C       ACG
```

Answer (score 0):

Taking care of allowable positions in the string:

```
awk -F"\t" '{printf $0 "\t"; if ($4 > 1) { printf substr($3, 1, $4 - 1) }; printf $6; if ($4 < length($3)) { printf substr($3, $4 + 1) }; printf "\n"}'
```

Or perhaps a bit more understandably:

```
awk -F"\t" 'BEGIN { OFS = FS } { if ($4 > 1) { mod = substr($3, 1, $4 - 1) }; mod = mod $6; if ($4 < length($3)) { mod = mod substr($3, $4 + 1) }; print $0, mod }'
```

And since `substr` doesn't appear to care all that much about bounds:

```
awk -F"\t" 'BEGIN { OFS = FS } { mod = substr($3, 1, $4 - 1) $6 substr($3, $4 + 1); print $0, mod }'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -plane 'substr($F[2],$F[3]-1,1)=$F[5]; $_.="\t$F[2]"' data
```

- change F2 according to the question `substr($F[2],$F[3]-1,1)=$F[5]`
- and concatenate it to the input line `$_.="\t$F[2]"`